# Run PHP file from within vim

Tags: php, vim

Is it possibly to run a PHP file from within vim? What im trying to do here is having a shortcut so whenever I need to run the file I'm editing to skip exiting vim and calling the PHP interpreter manually

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes! It's possible to do what you want. Both running PHP from within vim, and creating a shortcut.

Matthew Weier O'Phinney writes:

> Probably the most useful thing I've
>   done as a PHP developer is to add
>   mappings to run the current file
>   through (a) the PHP interpreter (using
>   Ctrl-M), and (b) the PHP interpreter's
>   linter (using Ctrl-L).

[Vim Productivity Tips for PHP Developers](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/164-Vim-Productivity-Tips-for-PHP-Developers.html)

Example:

```
:autocmd FileType php noremap <C-M> :w!<CR>:!/usr/bin/php %<CR>
```

Or (this doesn't check the filetype beware)

```
:map <C-M> :w!<CR>:!/usr/bin/php %<CR>
```

Joe 'Zonker' Brockmeier writes:

> Vim also allows you to execute a
>   command directly from the editor,
>   without needing to drop to a shell, by
>   using bang (!) followed by the command
>   to be run. For instance, if you're
>   editing a file in Vim and want to find
>   out how many words are in the file,
>   run

```
:! wc %
```

[Vim tips: Working with external commands](http://www.linux.com/archive/feed/57727)

Comment: Mapping to CTRL-M doesn't work, it does nothing at all. Doesn't save or execute php %

Comment: Mapping works, but it must have something to do with autocmd in the example. Try mapping directly to see if it works?

Comment: Must be some configuration thingy http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#FileType it only works when i issue set filetype=php before mapping. Not the intended effect i'm sure.

Comment: setting `:nocompatible` and `:set filetype = on` should work. Filetype will automagically set the filetype for the current document and nocompatible will make sure it works, since Vi doesn't allow filetype specific stuff.

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
:!php %
```

`%` stands for the current document, and `:!` executes any shell command.

You can also create a shortcut for it.

Comment: @shin Press the `Enter` key

Answer (score 1):

I have this in my .vimrc

```
" set make command when editing php files
set makeprg=php\ -l\ %
set errorformat=%m\ in\ %f\ on\ line\ %l
```

and then I map to F7 (or whatever you want) with:

```
:map <F7> :make <CR>
```

Comment: i also added `:autocmd FileType php noremap <C-M> :w!<CR>:!/usr/bin/php %<CR>
:map <F8> :w!<CR>:!/usr/bin/php %<CR>` as @Peter said on my .vimrc so i can also run the program and see it's output